# Problems with routing to VPN or ISP based on source IP

Tags: routing, openvpn

I'm trying to set up my DD-WRT router so that it directs traffic either through my VPN, or directly through my ISP, depending on the subnet of the requesting machine. In my case specifically, the subnet (either 192.168.0.0 or 2.0) is assigned based on the SSID a device is connected to, and that part seems to work fine. **However, all traffic seems to go through the VPN, not just traffic from the 192.168.2.0 subnet, as I'd intended**. The instructions I've been following are from here: https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/OpenVPN_on_Dedicated_Wireless_Access_Point_(VAP) The article notes the author was unsuccessful in getting this to work past a certain build, but their error message was related to TLS auth, which I don't think is relevant here.

The VPN is NordVPN, and the connection instructions I followed are here: https://nordvpn.com/tutorials/dd-wrt/openvpn-gui/ with one difference--I kept my DNS at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 rather than Nord's DNS.

These are the commands I run at startup (45 seconds seems to be more than enough time for the VPN to connect successfully):

```
sleep 45;
tun_name=$(ifconfig | sed -n 's/.*\(tun[^ ]\).*/\1/p');
tun_addr=$(ifconfig $tun_name | sed -nr 's/.*P-t-P:([^ ]+) .*/\1/p');
ip rule add from 192.168.2.0/24 table 200;
ip route add default via $tun_addr dev $tun_name table 200;
ip route flush cache;
```

The variables *tun_name* and *tun_addr* resolve to *tun1* and *10.8.8.247* respectively.

These are the results of running *ip rule show*

```
0:      from all lookup local
32765:  from 192.168.2.0/24 lookup 200
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

These are the results of running *ip route show*

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.8.1 dev tun1
default via 112.205.0.1 dev vlan2
10.8.8.0/24 dev tun1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.8.247
23.19.87.228 via 112.205.0.1 dev vlan2
112.205.0.0/19 dev vlan2  proto kernel  scope link  src 112.205.8.123
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  scope link
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.8.1 dev tun1
169.254.0.0/16 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.255.1
192.168.0.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.1
192.168.2.0/24 dev br1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.1
```

As far as I can tell, this table should work. One thing I did try was adding this to my startup script right before the flush, as I thought the entry might have been forcing everything to go through tun1:

```
ip route del 0.0.0.0/1 table main
```

However, while the entry was deleted properly, this didn't help, and all traffic is still sent through the VPN. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your VPN connection already routes everything to the VPN. It doesn't replace the default route, it creates two more specific routes.

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.8.1 dev tun1
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.8.1 dev tun1
```

By deleting `0.0.0.0/1` traffic to addresses above `128.0.0.0` still goes to the VPN.

You have to remove both, or avoid accepting the route from the VPN server (see the OpenVPN `pull` options)

Comment: Awesome, I tested it across multiple devices and it works! I guess I need to add 128.0.0.0/1 to my vocabulary of important IP rules to look at when I have routing issues. Thanks so much!